# How to set the focus on the last element in a grid view in android

Tags: android, gridview, android-gridview

I  am loading elements in a `GridView` at *runtime* and asking user if he wants to load more elements on a button click.What i want to achieve is that the focus should be on the last element of the `GridView` and not on the first element.

Comment: In the model class , make one boolean flag i.e isLastElement, in starting make it false , when the last element is visiable make it true , and if true then make that gridview focusable

Answer (score 0):

gridView.setSelection(gridView.getAdapter().getCount()-1);